# webpack + babel + ES2015, unexpected token import

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I know there are a lot similar topic here.

I try to solve by myself but I messed up.

I use

Sublime

Livereload(Sublime package, Windows application and chrome extension)

Sublime server

then Chrome console show me:

```
Navigated to http://localhost:8080/es6/
Hello world! (from webpack) with an autimatic update        bundle.js:73 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import                 index.js:3
```

I try a lot of way, but they doesn't work for me.

All npm install are local.

./index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>ES6</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./.build/bundle.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

./app/index.js

```
console.log('Hello world!');

import { fellowship, total } from './app/fellowship.js';
console.log( fellowship, total );
```

I try 'fellowship' 'fellowship.js' './fellowship' './app/fellowship'

No one worked.

./app/fellowship.js

```
const fellowship = ['frodo', 'Samwise', 'Gandalf'];
const total = fellowship.length;
export { fellowship, total };
```

./babelrc

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "check-es2015-constants",
    "transform-es2015-block-scoping"
  ]
}
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

./package.json

```
{
  "name": "es6",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "transpile-es2015": "babel src -d lib",
  },
  "babel": {
    "preset": [
      "es2015"
    ]
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2"
  }
}
```

./webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: ['./app/index.js'],
    output: {
        path: '.build',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
    module: {
        loaders: [
        {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
        }]
    },
}
```

Comment: probably because you are loading both source and built file in html. try removing index.js from index.html.

Comment: If I remove index.js, the index.html can't read index.js correctly.

Comment: bundle.js is compiled from index.js so no need to include both. Is there any specific reason you are loading both?

Comment: index.html can't show any content which in index.js. that why I loading index.js.